# Regular Expression for strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, lua

I wish to create a regular expression in Python 3 for lua long strings.

They should be of the following format:

they should start with "[" followed by 0 or more "=" and then "[" again.
That should then be followed by the string and completed with a: "]", then the same number of equals and "]" again.

For example:

```
[[ hello world ]]
```

or

```
[===[ hello world ]===]
```

or

```
[====[ trick ]==] still ]===] in the ]========] string ]====]
```

I am using python3 if that matters

Comment: You say at the top you want a lua regular expression, then at the bottom you say Python. Which is it?

Comment: I'm writing in python, but the [==[ syntax is lua syntax. I'll edit my question to  avoid confusion

Comment: If they need the same number of `=` on both sides, why does the last example have a single (i.e., unmatched) stretch of eight of them?

Comment: becuase that is not the end of the string. it is matched with the "]====]"

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the whole line is the valid match. It doesn't stop at `]=]`

Comment: Thats correct. The whole line: `[====[ trick ]==] still ]===] in the ]========] string ]====]` is a valid match

Comment: I'd suggest [`\[(=*?)\[([^\]]*(?:\](?!\1\])[^\]]*)*)\]\1\]`](https://regex101.com/r/bT5zZ3/3) that is an "unrolled" version of iismathwizard's answer.

Comment: Search for any active lua parsers for python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're asking for:

```
\[(=*?)\[(.*?)\]\1\]

\[            #matches '[' literally
    (         #first capture group
        =*?   #match the smallest number of concurrent '=' signs to make this match valid
    )
\[            #matches '[' literally
    (         #second capture group (this is if you just want the string value)
        .*?   #matches the smallest number of characters to make this match valid
    )
\]            #matches ']' literally
    \1        #match an exact copy of the first capture group (makes sure both sides have the same number of equal signs)
\]            #matches ']' literally
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sE7lS2/1)

Comment: Wow! could you please explain it?

Comment: @YahyaUddin certainly! i'll edit the explanation in now

Comment: Wow i didn't even know about the \1 thing!

Comment: Wait isn't this the same as: `\[(=*)\[(.*?)\]\1\]`, as the following `[` is required

Comment: @YahyaUddin yes and no. The difference here is, by using `*` you are prone to much more backtracking therefore making it less efficient. If you use `*?` it won't backtrack (assuming valid formatted strings)